# New to Excel-VBA: Run Time Error "91": Object Variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel-VBA so please excuse my ignorance. ;)

I'm actually trying to run a program on the selected sheet from a UserForm.
The program would then get a value from the selected sheet which would import it to a newly created sheet. Sheet18 is a sheet template it will be copied to the new sheet.

This are the codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Hide
  Dim wsUserSel As Worksheet
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ExFund As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsUserSel = ListBox1.Value
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    On Error GoTo 0
        With wsUserSel
            ExFund = .Cells(107, 4).Value
        End With
        Sheet18.Range("A1:K126").Copy
        ws.Name = InputBox("Please input the name of new worksheet.", ThisWorkbook.Name)
        ws.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Cells(29, 2) = ExFund
        ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This code returns an error

> Run Time Error "91": Object Variable or With block variable not set

because of this part of the code:

```
    With wsUserSel
        ExFund = .Cells(107, 4).Value
    End With
```

I have tried putting it inside With or using wsUserSel directly but I can't seem to get it working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `On Error Resume Next` statement is masking the error you are getting on the line saying

```
Set wsUserSel = ListBox1.Value
```

That line will fail because `ListBox1.Value` will not be a `Worksheet` object.  I assume it is a `String` that specifies which worksheet you want to use.

---

So change the section saying:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wsUserSel = ListBox1.Value
Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
On Error GoTo 0
```

to be:

```
Set wsUserSel = Worksheets(ListBox1.Value)
Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
```

Comment: Thank you YowE3k. Your answer was spot on!